# url shortning in code in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

my controller `

```
class index extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
  }

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
}
`   public function home()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('index');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

the url of function home in this controller is this
http://localhost:88/mlmm/index.php/index/home

i want this url to be
http://localhost:88/mlmm/home

Answer (score 1):

To remove **index.php** from your URL you need to add .htaccess file and below code inside that.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

for making url like this http://localhost:88/mlmm/home you need to mention routes in your **config/routes.php** file

```
$route['home'] = 'index/home';
```

**Note** : you have mention the controller name **index** and in codeigniter by default controller first method is also **index** so this can be make problem so I suggest use different controller name.